# Time Manager single point for time frame

Tags: qgis, timemanager

[image: repeating points]I'm using time manager for QGIS to create an animation. I am animating locations of buses. Their locations were sampled between every 2-5 minutes. So if I have a time window of 5 minutes, it will sometimes show two or more points for a single bus. I'm basically trying to figure out how to show only one point for a vehicle_id per time frame. Additionally when I interpolating points I lose the attributes so can't seem to style interpolated data.

Comment: This is multiple questions, please [edit] your post to a single question.

Comment: Regarding your first question, it's a bit confusing but I think you'll need to filter the data so there's only one point for each bus within each time 5 minute interval.

Answer (score 1):

If the desired animation time frame is shorter than 5 minutes, the interpolation option is the way to go.

If the desired animation time frame is 5 minutes or longer, it will be necessary to down-sample the movement data before loading it into TimeManager.