# Creating animated line moving between points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, time, animation, datetime

I have a point file, with Date:Time enabled. Rather than just animate the cycling through of points, I would like to have a line moving in a straight direction from one point to another in date order.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Based on [Babel's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438399/interpolating-points-with-qgis-native-temporal-controller/438402#438402) I have tried the following:

```
with_variable (
    'zone',
    0,  -- change this value to add/subtract hours to/from attribute named arrival_time to transform local time zone to UTC
    with_variable(
        'arrival',
        Date_time + to_interval (@zone  || ' days'),
        with_variable(
            'next',
            attribute (get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id+1), 'Date_time'),
            with_variable (
                'mapstart',
                @map_start_time + to_interval ((second (@map_end_time - @map_start_time)/2 ) || ' seconds'),
                with_variable (
                    'line',
                    make_line (
                        $geometry,
                        geometry( get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id+1))
                    ),
                end
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

My data contains a Date-time column of the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`. With a few exceptions all are set to 13:00:00 for the time, which is not so important. The only time this is different is when I have rows of the same day, and so would then control for them with different times.

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438402/88814 Just leave away the end_point() function to get a line, not point moving

Comment: @Babel, finally getting around to trying this, thanks for the help. My features are day by day so I have modified your code to the below, but not seeing anything? I've edited my original post.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing your data+project

Comment: @Babel, I have added more description of my data in the first post. As far as I can tell I have set up my project as in the link you shared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a point layer with two fields :

- `id` : unique integer field
- `dt_field` : date time field, format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

I just created a symbol layer for the point layer with **geometry generator** symbol type, `linestring` geometry type.

As geometry generator expression, I wrote the following code :

```sql
with_variable('data', array_agg("id", order_by:="dt_field"),
with_variable('id_index', array_find(@data, "id"),
with_variable('next_feature', get_feature(@layer, 'id', array_get(@data, @id_index + 1)),
    make_line($geometry, geometry(@next_feature))
)))
```

1. I created an array with `id` field values ordered by the Date Time field `@data`
2. I retrieved the current feature `id` index position in the `@data` array
3. I searched for the next Date Time feature, so the feature that is next in the `@data` array (or `@id_index + 1`) : `@next_feature`
4. I created a line starting from the current geometry `$geometry` (use `@geometry` since QGIS 3.28) to the next feature geometry `geometry(@next_feature)`

With temporal controller activated and the point layer temporal settings sets on the `dt_field`, you can see the line moving through the time.