# How do I animate paths from points using temporal controller on QGIS, or in other words, connect points from a user with a line that changes w time

Tags: qgis, animation, trajectory

I want to animate people moving using  temporal controller. I have a dataset that shows people's locations on a particular day, and these locations are points. I, however, want the points for each user to be united by a line across periods.

My data looks like this:

[image]

I have tried using the points to path tool, and that generates the paths I want but they don't animate.

I tried drawing the lines by creating geographic symbology, but for some reason, I only seem to be getting a line between the point at time 0 and all the other points at time 1,2,3 instead of a line between points 0-1, 1-2, 2-3.

The code that I tried is:

```
with_variable('data', array_agg("user", order_by:="week"), 
with_variable('user_index', array_find(@data, "user"), 
with_variable('next_feature', get_feature(@layer, 'user', array_get(@data, 
@user_index + 1)), make_line($geometry, geometry(@next_feature)) )))
```

For context, my second attempt is from this thread: [Creating animated line moving between points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443413/creating-animated-line-moving-between-points-in-qgis/458373#458373)

Comment: I have also now tried @Babel 's solution in this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445729/interpolating-points-with-qgis-native-temporal-controller-in-chronological-order but it seems to get rid of the lines entirely.