# Adding missing times to empty points

Tags: qgis, time, animation

I'm trying to create an animated map showing the trains moving on these lines. I have the arrival and departure times for each stations, names, all the data I need. But in order to make a smooth animation I have to transform the rail network in points, which I did for a line, but these points are empty and I want to give them an arrival and departure time in order to use the Temporal Animation Controller.

How should I do this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are some screenshots from my attribute table, regarding more info. I have the data from a gtfs which didn't contain the shape.txt and I have to use my own railnetwork because the routes.txt would follow the points not the geometry of the rail network.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UYtDiDnYVgRQK161o9DKNALebGW8QFaX?usp=share_link) is the data I'm using, the train stops and train network, I already tried geometry generator but they seem to appear only in the train station then dissapear.

---

[image]

[image]

Here are some screenshots from my attribute table, regarding more info. I have the data from a gtfs which didn't contain the shape.txt and I have to use my own railnetwork because the routes.txt would follow the points not the geometry of the rail network.

Comment: Can you share the data?

Comment: @BERA, I'm new to this platfom so I don't know how to share the data, do you mean a screenshot or a link to download it?

Comment: You don't need to create additional points. You can simply interpolate them, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438402/88814

Comment: @Babel I added a link here so if you want to see the data, I tried geometry generator but got stuck with it. https://cfr.webgis.ro/ This is an example of what i'm trying to achieve.