# Isolating points from a line shapefile (and check the attributes from specific points) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, splitting

I am new to QGIS and spatial data handling. I have a shapefile of a boat track and a shapefile of the border between two countries in QGIS. Parts of the boat tracks are in the waters from country 1 and parts are in the waters from country 2.

I would like to know the time at which the boat enters waters from country 1 and 2. Problem: My attribute tables for my boat track shapefile is by segment only (it does have time-stamp data but only by segment). I cannot manage to isolate the attributes of a specific point wihtin that segment, it keeps giving me attributes of the whole segment for all the points. I tried splitting the line (can't manage to do that, not sure what I am doing wrong), extracting vertices (but it still gives me the attributes of the segment only for all the verticles). How could I achieve this?

Comment: By splitting the lines, you won't get additional data, but just the data initially saved in the feature. The only way would be interpolating (calculating) values between start- and endpoint. See here for inspiration: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438402/88814 Generally, your question should be more specific to be able to give advice.

Comment: How is the shapefile created - in which tool? What you would need is actual point data (not lines with segments) where each point has some date / time information stored. A data format ideal for this is [GPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format). Still you would need to interpolate between the two nearest points on the border.